# Can't run db:create/migrate using jenkins to run unity tests of Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, svn, jenkins, rake

My `rake db:create db:migrate` works fine in my dev environment. When I commit it to subversion and add it to jenkins I get this error:

```
$ rake db:create
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- set
/opt/jenkins/jobs/job_db/workspace/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/jenkins/jobs/BPC-MaaS_TestRuns/workspace/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/jenkins/jobs/job_db/workspace/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I run it with `--trace` and I still have no idea what is wrong:

```
$ rake db:create --trace
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- set
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/index.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/source/rubygems.rb:72:in `specs'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/lazy_specification.rb:53:in `__materialize__'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in `block in materialize'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:132:in `specs'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:177:in `specs_for'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/definition.rb:166:in `requested_specs'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/environment.rb:18:in `requested_specs'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:13:in `setup'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler.rb:121:in `setup'
/usr/share/gems/gems/bundler-1.7.2/lib/bundler/setup.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:60:in `rescue in require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
/opt/jenkins/jobs/BPC-MaaS_TestRuns/workspace/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/opt/jenkins/jobs/BPC-MaaS_TestRuns/workspace/config/application.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/opt/jenkins/jobs/BPC-MaaS_TestRuns/workspace/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:687:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/usr/share/gems/gems/rake-10.3.2/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/share/gems/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/usr/share/gems/bin/rake:23:in `<main>'
```

PS: All the gems in Gemfile are installed.

UPDATE: Here's my `gem env` with Ruby version. I have to work with internal packages of the gems not the "original" ones:

```
RubyGems Environment:
- RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.23
- RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-11-22 patchlevel 484) [x86_64-linux]
- INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/share/gems
- RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby
- EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/share/gems/bin
- RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
  - ruby
  - x86_64-linux
- GEM PATHS:
   - /usr/share/gems
   - /opt/ruby
   - /opt/<company>/ruby
   - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
- GEM CONFIGURATION:
   - :update_sources => true
   - :verbose => true
   - :benchmark => false
   - :backtrace => false
   - :bulk_threshold => 1000
   - "gemhome" => "/usr/share/gems"
   - "gempath" => ["/opt/ruby", "/opt/<company>/ruby", "/usr/share/gems", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
   - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0):

Requires additional information about your build environment:

1) `ruby -v` - version of ruby

2) `gem env` - settings of rubygems

Comment: Added to my question. Sorry for the late reply :)